# How do i make "Sphinx Service" start automatically and run nonstop?

Tags: php, linux, sphinx

I have installed sphinx-0.9.9 in my LINUX server and it gives the result nicely.

The problem is *"the searchd.pid file is getting deleted often"* (service stops automatically). I

I couldn't find the reason why it stops. Can anybody tell me the reason and also how could I make this service run all the time nonstop, even when I reboot the system the service should restart automatically.

Timely help is highly appreciated

Thanks in Advance,
Raja.M

Comment: Is the server running out of resources? The system could be killing it off automatically.

Comment: No it is a big Server, I'm sure that it may not be the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You might be interested in having a look at [Supervisor](http://supervisord.org/). In particular, in the documentation section regarding how to configure a [program](http://supervisord.org/configuration.html#program-x-section-values), you'll see the following options:

```
autostart
    If true, this program will start automatically when supervisord is started.
...
autorestart
    May be one of false, unexpected, or true. [...]
    If true, the process will be unconditionally restarted when it exits,
    without regard to its exit code.
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. But I"m not getting the thing right to solve my issue. Can anybody come out with a solution.

Answer (score 0):

The sphinx.pid file gets deleted on every reboot. You can remove and install sphinxsearch again to recreate it.